# How to make fonts in VSCode like in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, fonts

I've been using vscode for a while, and i just recently tried android studio. Immediately I realized that I like the fonts in android studio more than the fonts in vscode. How do I make fonts in VSCode like fonts in Android Studio? Thank you.
this is the comparison :

[image: font appearance in Android Studio and VSCode]

Comment: you can use any font you like in VSC, find the name of the android studio font and find an equivalent for your OS and use it in VSC

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact font Android Studio uses, but you can change your editor font to a monospace font like this:

Open your VS code settings file by bringing up the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and run the `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` command. Add the following line:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
```

The leftmost existing font that is available on your PC is used, the remaining ones are fallback options. If you know exactly which installed font you want to use you can simply set it to this value:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "My Favourite Font",
```